# Searching for specific files using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to capture two specific words/sequence of characters in a filename in a folder. What I have so far gives correct output on https://regex101.com/ but not in my script I'm working with.

This is the type of filenames I'm working with:

```
Bjørn Stallaresvei s 10013.pdf
```

or

```
Københavngaten 1 L. 8.pdf
```

And this is the regex I've come up with so far:

```
((?<=\s)[a-zA-Z\.]+(?=[\s0-9]+\.pdf))|((?<=\s)[0-9]+(?=.pdf))
```

I'm trying to capture in the first line 's' and '10013' - where 's' is the identifier and 10013 is the ID.

Same in the second line, L. is the identifier and 8 is the ID.

This is just an example code to show:

```
import re

string_1 = "Stallaresvei s 10013.pdf"

regexp = r"(((?<=\s)[a-zA-Z\.]+(?=[\s0-9]+\.pdf))|((?<=\s)[0-9]+(?=.pdf)))"
m = re.search(regexp, string_1)

print(m)
```

And the output only displays one match found:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(13, 14), match='s'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may remove the capturing parentheses and use your regex with `re.findall`:

```
r'(?<=\s)[a-zA-Z.]+(?=[\s0-9]+\.pdf)|(?<=\s)[0-9]+(?=\.pdf)'
```

See the [online Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/5n9Gz0):

```
import re
string_1 = "Stallaresvei s 10013.pdf"
regexp = r"(?<=\s)[a-zA-Z.]+(?=[\s0-9]+\.pdf)|(?<=\s)[0-9]+(?=\.pdf)"
m = re.findall(regexp, string_1)
print(m) # => ['s', '10013']
```

Another way is to rewrite the pattern and *capture* these bits into 2 groups, see [another demo](https://ideone.com/Tln7Zi):

```
import re
string_1 = "Stallaresvei s 10013.pdf"
regexp = r"\s([a-zA-Z.]+)\s+([0-9]+)\.pdf"
m = re.search(regexp, string_1)
if m:
    print([m.group(1), m.group(2)])
```

Here,

- `\s` - matches  a whitespace
- `([a-zA-Z.]+)` - Capturing group 1 matches 1+ ASCII letters or `.`
- `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
- `([0-9]+)` - Capturing group 2 matches 1+ ASCII digits
- `\.pdf` - just matches `.pdf` substring.

Comment: I was so close :) Thank you for this!